# Can not convert html to png using phantomjs or wkhtmltoimage

Tags: html, image, phantomjs, wkhtmltoimage

I want to convert html to png.

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  main {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto;
  }

  header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  header .content {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 40px 0;
  }

  .content .column {
    width: 25%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .content .column.lfp-logo {
    width: 30%;
  }

  .content .column img {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<main>
  <header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="column"><img
        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1237/5652/products/spiderman_3_compression_shirt_3_small.jpg"></div>
      <div class="column lfp-logo"><img
        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1237/5652/products/spiderman_3_compression_shirt_3_small.jpg"></div>
      <div class="column"><img
        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1237/5652/products/spiderman_3_compression_shirt_3_small.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is jsfiddle example. this is actually what i need to get in my png file [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8fb95kx/)

I tried to use `wkhtmltoimage` and I get this image[image]

Also I tried to use `phantomjs` and get this image
[image]
I use phantomjs with nodejs module `webshot`.

Can anyone suggest me way I can render html to png image.
I dont need dynamic html. All I want to render is static.

> UPDATE. Added code for generating images

```
const pug = require('pug');
const child_process = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');
const webshot = require('webshot');

const options = {
    data: {
        images: {
            header: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1237/5652/products/spiderman_3_compression_shirt_3_small.jpg',
            team1: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1237/5652/products/spiderman_3_compression_shirt_3_small.jpg',
            team2: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1237/5652/products/spiderman_3_compression_shirt_3_small.jpg',
            competition: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1237/5652/products/spiderman_3_compression_shirt_3_small.jpg'
        }
    }
};

const html = pug.renderFile('./template/next.pug', options);

console.log(html); // this is html

// webshot with wkhtmltoimage
child_process.exec(`echo "${html}" | wkhtmltoimage --width 600 --disable-smart-width - export/out.png`, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

// webshot with phantomjs
webshot(html, 'hello_world.png', {siteType:'html'}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Gor, you forgot to include a sample code of your script that makes a screenshot.

Comment: ok @Vaviloff I will update now

Answer (score -1):

I would say to make something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/roberburnday/d4mggqwv/). Working with [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) you can do it easy and fast.

```
    convert_to_img = function (do_download) {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("contenedor_chimichangas"), {
    //onrender devuelve el canvas para hacerle los retoques necesarios
    onrendered: function (canvas) {//sombra aqui, sombra allí!! 
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');//context from originalCanvas
      var data_image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); //cogemos la url de la imagen sin tratar
      //añadimos la url en una imagen para poder tratarla y redimensionarla
      var image_edicion = $("<img/>", {
        id: "image",
        src: data_image
      }).appendTo($("#show_img").empty());
        //if we click download:
        if(do_download === true){
          Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(new_canvas);
        }
      });

    },

  });
}
```

The js are documented line at line. ;D

Comment: I cant use Html2Canvas or other libs like it. because conversation must be server side